# Prestashop quantity changes to remote database

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

So, my client has multiple online stores and a new Prestashop installed.
He also have one database where he keeps all the products quantities in one place.
Just quantities, linked to stores by id or something.

Now what I have to do is post info to the warehouse server everytime Prestashop product quantity changes eg. when order is coming, product is updated from admin, order is cancelled or what ever that makes changes to the quantities.

How can I do that kind of module to Prestashop or is there any another way to do this?
I don't need full source, but a little bit help would be nice.
I know basics about Prestashops modules, but this is tricky.

There is somekind of API in the warehouse that works with get-parameters.

```
http://link-to-warehouse-api/?product_id=id&new_quantity=n
```

Hope you understand what I mean. :)

Comment: You’ll probably want to look into the _hooks_ prestashop offers for this, something like `actionUpdateQuantity` could be about the right one to use.

Comment: as @CBroe said you said use action hooks, like actionValidateOrder, this hooks are executed when action are triggered